# Python - Convert a signed float to Unsigned Long( DWORD for win32 )

Tags: python, c++, type-conversion

I know python doesn't have unsigned variables but I need to convert one from a program that runs python( Blender ) to a win32 application written in C++. I know I can convert an integer like so:

```
>>> int i = -1

>>> _ + 2**32
```

How can I take a float like: 0.2345f and convert it to a long type? I will need to convert to long in python and then back to float in win32( c++ )...

typically in C++ it is down by

```
>>>float f = 0.2345f;

>>>DWORD dw = *reinterpret_cast< DWORD* >( &f );
```

this produces an unsigned long ... and to convert it back is simply the reverse:

```
>>>FLOAT f = *reinterpret_cast< FLOAT* >( &dw );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `struct.pack` and `struct.unpack` for this. Note though that it is not a cast (i.e. a reinterpretation of the same memory), but a converter (copy to a new piece of memory).

```
import struct

def to_float(int_):
    return struct.unpack('d', struct.pack('q', int_))[0]

def to_long(float_):
    return struct.unpack('q', struct.pack('d', float_))[0]


data = 0.2345
long_data= to_long(data) #4597616773191482474
new_data = to_float(long_data) #0.2345
```

Answer (score 0):

i = 0.2345

converted = long(i)

Comment: long() is not available anymore in python 3.x ... and using int(i) is like using floor or ceil... I need to be able to convert the floating point variable to long in python and then back to a float in win32...

Comment: I didn't realize you were using python 3.